# Why is the aggregate function being applied to the grouping column?

Tags: r, aggregate

there is a simple aggregate:

```
dat = read.table(textConnection(
  'ID value
  1 4
  1 7
  2 8
  2 3
  2 3'), header = TRUE)

aggregate(dat,by=list("type"=dat$ID),sum)
```

i get the result output:

```
       type ID value
    1    1  2    11
    2    2  6    14
```

i wonder:
1.in the first row ,why the ID  is 2?
2.in the second row ,why the ID  is 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You requested a sum of each column, aggregated by`dat$ID`.  Using this interface, that will include all columns.  `dat$ID` is simply a vector and thus the `ID` column is not removed from the aggregated results.  The function `sum` is also applied to `ID` within each group.

For the first row, you are computing `with(dat, sum(ID[dat$ID==1]))` or 1+1.
For the second row, you are computing `with(dat, sum(ID[dat$ID==2]))` or 2+2+2
(It is intentional that I specified `dat$ID` in each index, rather than `ID`, as that is what your `aggregate` call is doing.)

Using the formula interface to `aggregate` is cleaner, and gives what you seem to want.  Using this interface, `aggregate` gives the sum of the `value` column, with `ID` as it appears in each aggregated group:

```
> aggregate(value ~ ID, data=dat, sum)
  ID value
1  1    11
2  2    14
```